# Test Liferay portal using Selenium

Tags: selenium, liferay

I want to test a Liferay portlet with Selenium, but the problem is that element ids generated by Liferay are dynamic and seems that they change each time I enter portlet. Does anyone has any suggestion how I test the portlet?

thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure how but Liferay uses Selenium internally to test Liferay Portal. So I know its possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on how your elements are structured.  There are various ways to identify elements and not just fixed ids.

If you have dynamic element ids, then try using some other attributes of the elements to uniquely identify elements for eg, text() or  name etc...  At times, it also happens that ids are generated with a common pattern, in which case you can try using that for eg, //div[contains(@id,'fixedpart')]
or //div[starts-with(@id,'fixedpart')]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use new HTML5 attribute like data-*, for example for a certain

```
<div data-selenium-test = "foo"></div>
```

Then grab this element with selenium:

```
//div[@data-selenium-test='foo']
```